# Server Still Picking up file after Deleted it through code asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I deleted a file using System.IO.delete(path) and It was successfull, I even deleted the files manually by navigating into project folder, but still when I run the project it picks up the old file rather then new file.

```
<img src='Images/<%# Eval("post_image") %>' class="PostImage img-responsive" />
```

Here I have inserted a new file but server still picks up the deleted file.
A help would be nice

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: No I didn't but this might not be the solution

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a caching issues.

I suggest you give your file a unique name, you can create it randomly or use a timestamp to make sure the filename will always be different.

Comment: I tried to give filename a timestamp but it includes "\,: " and charcters like this so it didn't work

Comment: you need to format it, windows dont allow special characters on filename

Comment: @Hannan for example check this http://www.dotnetperls.com/filename-datetime , you can make it even simpler